# How to Replace specific range of string with a character?

Tags: swift, string

I'm using swift in my project. I want to change a specific range of string with a character. for example I have a string "1234567890" and I want to change characters in range, location 5 and length 3 to "*". the out put should be "12345****90".

I see a ways for doing this by converting string to NSString and using this function:

> stringByReplacingCharactersInRange

but is there any better way? a swift way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to write that in Swift in one line:

```swift
let stringA = "1234567890"
let stringB = String(stringA.enumerated().map { !(5...7).contains($0) ? $1 : "*" })
let stringC = String(stringA.enumerated().compactMap { !(5...7).contains($0) ? $1 : $0 == 5 ? "*" : nil })

print(stringB) // "12345***90\n"
print(stringC) // "12345*90\n"
```

Just to add some explanation:
We enumarate the `String` so we can use the *indexes* to map the `Character`s based on their position on the `String`. On the closure, `$0` corresponds to the offset and `$1` to the `Character` on the iteration. It could also be written as `$0.offset` and `$0.element`, respectively.
On the second example with `stringC`, where it replaces with only one `*`, we replace the `Character` in position *5* with the `*` and the rest with `nil`, and the `compactMap` will return all of the *non-`nil`* results.

Comment: what should I do if I want to replace range 5...7 with single "*" character?

Comment: this can also be written as `(5...7).contains($0) ? "*" : $1 `

Comment: @behrad `compactMap { !(5...7).contains($0) ? $1 : 5 == $0 ? "*" : nil }`

Comment: @behrad I've updated the answer considering the comments and added some explanations, hope it's all clear.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
var myString = "1234567890"
let startIndex = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
let endIndex = myString.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
myString.replaceSubrange(startIndex..<endIndex, with: "***")
    
print("\(myString)")
```

Write an extension if necessary

```
extension String {

    mutating func replaceSubString(startAt: Int, offsetBy: Int, with newString: String) {
        let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: startAt)
        let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: offsetBy)
        self.replaceSubrange(startIndex..<endIndex, with: newString)
    }
    
}
```

and you use it like this:

```
var myString = "1234567890"
myString.replaceSubString(startAt: 5, offsetBy: 3, with: "***")
print("\(myString)")
```

Comment: Better to extend StringProtocol and constrain Self to RangeReplaceableCollectiom to support substrings as well

Comment: And add the non mutating counterpart as well  replacingSubrange. I would also rename the method to replaceSubrange

Comment: And you don't need to return anything on a mutating method